# Can anyone explain how we will get the output of the following code in Lua?

Tags: lua, lua-table

```
function ReturnTwoVal()
return "1","2"
end
function ReturnThreeVals()
return "x","y","Z"
end
TblA = {ReturnThreeVals(),ReturnTwoVal() }
print(TblA[2],TblA[1], TblA[2], TblA[3], TblA[4])
```

Output will be: 1   x   1   2   nil

Comment: What does this have to do with `javascript`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expressions that return multiple values are adjusted to a single value, unless they are the last expression in a function call or table constructor.

Therefore,

```
TblA = {ReturnThreeVals(),ReturnTwoVal() }
```

is equivalent to

```
TblA = {"x", "1","2"}
```